# Is this the probability of intersection or is this the conditional probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In a search of $285$ asked people for the quality of a service the $130$ are men. The ones who are men and are satisfied from the quality are in percentage $30\%$ and the corresponding percentage for women is $25\%$.

Given that we have chosen a women which is the probability that she is satisfied.

$$$$

Suppose that "W" is the event "Woman", "M" the event "Man", "S" the event "Satisfied.

We want to calculate the conditional probability $P(S\mid W)=\frac{S\cap W}{P(W)}$, right?

We have that $P(W)=\frac{285-130}{285}=\frac{155}{130}$.

The point that I am confused is at the given information :

> The ones who are men and are satisfied from the quality are in percentage $30\%$ and the corresponding percentage for women is $25\%$.

Is this the probability of intersection or is this the conditional probability?

Comment: "Given that we have chosen a women, what is the probability that she is satisfied?" is asking for a conditional probability.  So it seems likely that "the corresponding percentage for women is 25%" was a joint probability.

Comment: Ok, so is that desired probability $P(S\mid W)=\frac{P(S\cap W)}{P(W)}=\frac{\frac{25}{100}}{\frac{155}{285}}=\frac{57}{124}\approx 0,46$ ? @Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The ones who are men **and** are satisfied" is $P(M\cap S)$. And "the corresponding percentage" is $P(S\cap W) = 25\%$. Because the "**and**" specifies that this is not a conditional probability, it is the intersection of the events "being a man/woman" **and** "being satisfied".

Also, your $P(W)$ should be $\dfrac{155}{285}$, not $\dfrac{155}{130}$ :)

*PS: Your Bayes' formula should be $P(S|W) = \dfrac{P(S\cap W)}{P(W)}$, not $P(S|W) = \dfrac{S\cap W}{P(W)}$ (which does not mean anything since $S\cap W$ is not a number, I'm assuming that was just a typo).*

Comment: Ok, so the desired probability is $\frac{\frac{25}{100}}{\frac{155}{285}}=\frac{57}{124}\approx 0,46$ , right?

Comment: Yes, that's it :)

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-)